# Enforcing minimum number of characters for #autocomplete_path

Tags: forms, ajax

I have a form that is using [`#autocomplete_path`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#autocomplete_path) on a textfield.  In general it works fine.

Is there a way to have the autocomplete callback not fire until a minimum number of characters have been entered?

Is the only real option to override `Drupal.ACDB.prototype.search` with my own version, or is there a clean way to do this?

I am not interested in server side solutions to limit the result set; I am trying to decrease server load here and really need a client-side solution to prevent useless requests from ever being generated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's two approaches:

1. Replace the entire `autocomplete.js` with your customized version

   ```
   /**
    * Implements hook_js_alter
    * Replace autocomplete.js with customized version
    */
   function MY_MODULE_js_alter(&$javascript) { 
     $javascript['misc/autocomplete.js']['data'] = drupal_get_path('module', 'MY_MODULE') . '/js/autocomplete.js';
   }
   ```
2. Override `Drupal.ACDB.prototype.search` with a custom version

Copy to theme script.js or module js file, as long as it's added after `/misc/autocomplete.js` it will override it.

```
(function($) {

/**
 * Performs a cached and delayed search.
 *
 * Override adds minimum text string length for lookup.
 * See /misc/autocomplete.js for original function.
 */
Drupal.ACDB.prototype.search = function (searchString) {

  // Minimum search string length
  var min = 3; 
  var db = this;
  this.searchString = searchString;

  // See if this string needs to be searched for anyway.
  searchString = searchString.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/, '');
  if (searchString.length <= min ||
    searchString.charAt(searchString.length - 1) == ',') {
    return;
  }

  // See if this key has been searched for before.
  if (this.cache[searchString]) {
    return this.owner.found(this.cache[searchString]);
  }
  // Initiate delayed search.
  if (this.timer) {
    clearTimeout(this.timer);
  }
  this.timer = setTimeout(function () {
    db.owner.setStatus('begin');

    // Ajax GET request for autocompletion. We use Drupal.encodePath instead of
    // encodeURIComponent to allow autocomplete search terms to contain slashes.
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: db.uri + '/' + Drupal.encodePath(searchString),
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (matches) {
        if (typeof matches.status == 'undefined' || matches.status != 0) {
          db.cache[searchString] = matches;
          // Verify if these are still the matches the user wants to see.
          if (db.searchString == searchString) {
            db.owner.found(matches);
          }
          db.owner.setStatus('found');
        }
      },
      error: function (xmlhttp) {
        alert(Drupal.ajaxError(xmlhttp, db.uri));
      }
    });
  }, this.delay);
};
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Number two is almost exactly what I am doing.  I did have to wrap it in a closure, though, to avoid "$ is undefined" errors.  It just makes me feel dirty...

Comment: Yes, I think it's sometimes referred to as [Monkey Patching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch) :) P.S jQuery namespace wrapper added to answer there.

Comment: @MPD , sorry I'm not understand, where to add the "Drupal.ACDB.prototype.search = function" function, will i replace it in autocomplete.js file itself.

Comment: @Bala You don't edit the core misc/autocomplete.js   You can put this in your our JS file that gets included in a module or a theme.  When your gets loaded, it will override the core declaration.

Comment: @MPD I put the autocomplete.js inside the custom module and I want to know where to add the 2 step ?

Comment: @Bala You can pretty much copy and paste the code into your own JS file.

Answer (score 2):

I am not suggesting that you should just go and edit this directly, but, the behavior is dictated by just having any characters entered into the input field.

Thus, you could change

```
if (input.value.length > 0)
```

to

```
if (input.value.length > WHATEVERVALUE)
```

around line 94 in `misc/autocomplete.js,` and, for D7, you could change

```
if (input.value.length > 0 && !input.readOnly) {
```

around line 102 similarly.

Of course, this will be creating a site wide behavior change (and hacked core) so maybe/hopefully there is a way to include a different `autocomplete.js` in for your specific form/form element (overriding `theme_textfield()` might work).

Comment: It's also possible to override just the `Drupal.ACDB.prototype.search` function in another js file, as MPD referred to in the question, which removes the need to alter the core file. Alternatively, hook_js_alter could be used to swap out `autocomplete.js` with a new file.

Comment: indeed, hence my last paragraph

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a clean way to do this persay besides overriding. D8 mostly re-wrote most of the autocomplete ajax because its a rather limited library in D7.

That being said if you dont want to override stuff you can always use the bundled jQuery and its auto-complete functions to do the same thing -- it doesnt end up being that much code. [Here is an example from a Russian blog for jquery autocomplete in Drupal 7 with a live example on the page](http://serho.ru/notes/raznoe/jquery-ui-autocomplete-widget-v-forme-drupal-7) which I have adopted on 1 of my own projects.