# How to increase the speed of exposed autocomplete field in views using drupal 6?

Tags: 6, views

I have an exposed auto-complete taxonomy filter, It takes time(2sec) to load the values. How to increase the **performance** to load the values quickly and I'm using views 2.x.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is Drupal 7 so slow?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/724/why-is-drupal-7-so-slow)

Comment: @Mołot sorry, I posted a question on meta http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2688/why-this-question-closed

Comment: How many terms?

Comment: I disagree that this is a duplicate.  There are one or two possible causes for this particular situation that aren't related to general Drupal slowness.

Comment: @MPD around 400 terms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming a Drupal installation configured for a production environment (including Apache and MySQL tuning), there are two things that impact autocomplete latency.

One, is a built-in delay between user input and running searches.  This is baked into misc/autocomplete.js.  The value is set to 300ms (line 245), and get used in `Drupal.ACDB.prototype.search` (line 287).

The second is that searches will run on a single character.  If your autocomplete result set is large, this can have huge performance impacts.

Unfortunately, there isn't a good way to alter either of these behaviors.  You can add your own Javascript and redeclare `Drupal.ACDB` to use a shorter delay, eg

```
Drupal.ACDB = function (uri) {
  this.uri = uri;
  this.delay = 100;
  this.cache = {};
};
```

and `Drupal.ACDB.prototype.search` to add in some logic to [enforce a minimum number of characters](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/78727), eg

```
...
// See if this string needs to be searched for anyway.
searchString = searchString.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/, '');
if (searchString.length <= min ||
  searchString.charAt(searchString.length - 1) == ',') {
  return;
}
...
```

However, 400 results isn't a huge number.  I have mainly seen the delays this with 10000+ results.  This suggests that you may need to do some additional profiling on your server.