# Autocomplete field search start character limitation?

Tags: ajax

How can I limit the number of characters on when the search starts send a request to the server?

What happens if I do for example always call my own API (in the sense of using the autocomplete_path attribute)? Is the minimum still 3 characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will you explain the search that you are using (ex.solr, default).
Basic limitation of characters is 3. if you want to increase this go to admin/config/search/settings and change the length of Minimum word length to index to **your-limit** and re-index the site. If you type minimum word length then only your search send a request to server.

Comment: But what happens if I do for example always call my own api? Is the minimum still 3 characters?

Comment: Own API in the sense are you customizing Search with you own API.
If so, then check for min-length (as required)  and hit your API to fetch results

Comment: Own API in the sense of using the autocomplete_path attribute

Comment: Check this http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/78727/enforcing-minimum-number-of-characters-for-autocomplete-path